# DagatridColumn header not properly bound

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

While binding a property to the header of a `DataGrid`, i get this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Strings.Address; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

The code:

```xml
<DataGridTextColumn
    MinWidth="80"
    Binding="{Binding Address, Converter={StaticResource AddressToStringConverter}}"
    IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Strings.Address, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Then I thought, let's use snoop to check what is actually going on in the bindings. But when I snoop the `TextBlock`, the binding suddenly works.

I have tried binding to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` above, same results.

Anyone an idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: sample project:

After searching some more, I found out that the issue is a `TabControl` that is the parent (See code below). I don't have any solution yet tough...

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:testapp="clr-namespace:TestApp">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <testapp:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Content="Breaks it" Header="Before" />
        <TabItem Header="Test">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Content="Doesn't break it" Header="After" />
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public string Name => "Name";
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>
    {
        new Person{Name="Mickey Mouse"},
    };
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

It appears that when the `DataGrid` is not in the first tab, the bindings don't work any mor.

Solutions?

Comment: How is `DataGrid` is defined? Please, show the object which is bound to `DataContext` also

Answer (score 1):

The `DataContext` of your `DataGridTextColumn` will be the `Address` property of your collection. If you're trying to bind to a property of your Page/Control `DataContext`, you'll need to find the parent control and bind to it's `DataContext`, something like:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Strings.Address, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

That works but if you need to bind more than a few items, the code becomes quite unclear and it is hard to debug when something goes wrong. What I like to do this days to simplify access to my main `DataContext` from within a different `DataContext` is to set it in the XAML itself:

```
<Page 
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:CoolApp1.Models"
   ...>
        <Page.DataContext>
             <models:MyModel x:Name="Context"/>
        </Page.DataContext>
```

And then you could do:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock Content="{Binding ElementName=Context, Path=Strings.Address}"/>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

I hope I understood the problem and this is helpful to you !

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do not bind to the DataContext of the DataGridTextColumn, I bind to the DataGrid. This has the same DataContext as the parent control since it is automatically passed through. (I also tried refering to the UserControls DataContext.) That asside, if the binding was incorrect, it should also not work when I inspect with snoop, but then it suddenly works.

Comment: Hmm it's hard for me to tell what is going on. There are a few factors involved. First is the DataContext of your DataGrid. Another is whether the property you're trying to bind implements notification...Other is the notification triggers and binding mode... Perhaps you could first try and change NotifyOnSourceUpdated to true in your binding? See if that helps

Comment: Been there, done that. All things are set-up as should (as far as i can see). The classes all implement INotifyPropertyChanged, I have been playing around with the triggers, itemsSource is properly bound (since I do get all the rows properly),... The only thing that won't work properly are the headers

Comment: Let me get this straight... you want to bind the `TextBox.Text` in your `DataGridTextColumn` to your `DataGrid`'s `DataContext.Strings.Address` ... right? If so, your `DataGrid` has to inherit a DataContext from a parent Element (which I thought was your UserControl/Page) that has that `String.Address` property. All good till there?

Comment: I want to bind the header of the `DataGridTextColumn` to the value of  `DataContext.Strings.Address` (eventually with tooltip that is why I use a `TextBlock`). The `DataContext` contains the needed properties and is bound correctly since I do get data in the `DataGrid` and all fields are visible. The headers however, are all empty because it can't find the Relative source to the parent element (`Data Error: 4`).